# multiline statement in sql patch files with liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase 3.2.3. Is it possibile to force liquibase to generate multiline statements in output sql patch files?

This is what I getting now:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (COLUMN0 NUMBER, COLUMN1 NUMBER, COLUMN2 NUMBER, COLUMN3 NUMBER, COLUMN4 NUMBER, COLUMN5 NUMBER, COLUMN6 NUMBER, COLUMN7 NUMBER, COLUMN8 NUMBER, COLUMN9 NUMBER);
```

But I want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
COLUMN0 NUMBER, 
COLUMN1 NUMBER, 
COLUMN2 NUMBER, 
COLUMN3 NUMBER, 
COLUMN4 NUMBER, 
COLUMN5 NUMBER, 
COLUMN6 NUMBER, 
COLUMN7 NUMBER, 
COLUMN8 NUMBER, 
COLUMN9 NUMBER);
```